# Create custom validation attributes c# server side

Tags: c#, validation, attributes, licensing

I'm trying to create Validation Attribute to enforce licensing in my solution.
The way I've tried to do it is using by **LicenseValidationAttribute** that inherits from **ValidationAttribute**.
The main goal is when CreateProject() method is called, if the customer already reached the limit of projects he is entitled for, that will lead to exception throwing. else, that will be OK flow.
I've write a small program but unfortunately it doesn't work, means it doesn't throws exception.
The program:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public MyValidationAttribute()
    {

    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        int id = (int)value;
        if (id > 0)
            return true;
        throw new Exception("Error");
    }
}

 public class Service
{
    [MyValidation]
    public bool GetService(int id)
    {
        if (id > 100)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Service service = new Service();
            service.GetService(-8);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); ;
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding System.reflection's `GetCustomAttributes` method call it works:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Service service = new Service();
            service.GetService(-8);
            service.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); ;
        }

    }
```